# querying a database after a Date in asp throws an incorrect syntax exception

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have been struggling to get the date from an asp database table and I managed with the following query:

```
SELECT p.nume, n.data_inceput,n.data_sfarsit,n.pret,n.id FROM hotel p ,rezervare n where p.ID = n.id_hotel and  (CONVERT(nvarchar(10), n.data_inceput, 101) LIKE '%date%'
```

This query is clearly working (god knows how much I searched until I stumbled across that convert) .

However when I try to execute this in the code I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near '%09/11/2014%'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '%09/11/2014%'.

Source Error:


Line 18:             conn.Open();
Line 19:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
Line 20:             SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 21:             FillTable(reader);
Line 22:             conn.Close();
```

With line 20 being the problem.

I have the following code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = GetQuery();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            FillTable(reader);
            conn.Close();
        }



private string GetQuery()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
           // DateTime start;
           // DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out start);
            query = string.Format("SELECT p.nume, n.data_inceput,n.data_sfarsit,n.pret,n.id FROM hotel p ,rezervare n where p.ID = n.id_hotel and  (CONVERT(nvarchar(10), n.data_inceput, 101) LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            query = string.Format("SELECT p.nume, n.data_inceput,n.data_sfarsit,n.pret,n.id FROM hotel p ,rezervare n where p.ID = n.id_hotel");
        }
        return query;
    }
```

What could be the problem ? I don't really know where to look

Comment: Your column is a `Date` or a `DateTime`?

Comment: it's was DateTime but I changed it to Date (still had the time there so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed a closing parenthesis at the end of your sql statement.

This

```
(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), n.data_inceput, 101) LIKE '%{0}%'
```

should change to this:

```
(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), n.data_inceput, 101) LIKE '%{0}%)'
```

Comment: oh, haha , maybe after a few hours I would have seen that, you rock! I will shortly accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You better you ISO date: **yyyyMMdd**.

So, in code behind:

```
private string GetQuery()
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out dt);

        query = string.Format("SELECT p.nume, n.data_inceput,n.data_sfarsit,n.pret,n.id FROM hotel p ,rezervare n where p.ID = n.id_hotel and n.data_inceput > '{0}' AND n.data_inceput < '{1}'", dt.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dt.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    }
    else
    {
        query = string.Format("SELECT p.nume, n.data_inceput,n.data_sfarsit,n.pret,n.id FROM hotel p ,rezervare n where p.ID = n.id_hotel");
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: no, I can't, but that's what that convert is for. It makes a string out of them, it's ok now it works . Thank you for trying to help me. Your code works perfectly fine also. I will leave this post so if others have problems with querying after a date in table they will see the 2 variants :D !